# Image not resizing properly with JS onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/oqczdudz/

```
document.getElementById('phonetype').addEventListener("change", function() {
  var phoneType = document.getElementById('phonetype').value;
  if (phoneType == "iPhone") {
      document.getElementById('tab1').innerHTML = '<img src="images/Device Icon - Apple 3.png" width="64" height="64" alt=""/>';
      document.getElementById('phone').style.background = "url('images/devices/iPhone%20Black.png')";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('tab1').innerHTML = '<img src="images/Device Icon - Samsung 3.png" width="64" height="64" alt=""/>';
    document.getElementById('phone').style.background = "url('images/devices/Samsung%20Black.png')";
}
  });
```

I have an image of a hollow iPhone case which is designed to have background colors and patterns show through it. The image is 350x568px. I want to dynamically change that picture from a dropdown selection, which I have done with a javascript event listener change function. The CSS code manages the image's width and height. However, when the iPhone is changed to a Samsung phone, the image shows up way too large and I do not understand why. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Here is the link to show you whats happening, Click "options" on the top left, change "Phone Type" to "Galaxy S7". You'll see what's going on.

http://www.matthewmwalker.com/sweetbriar/index.html

Thank you!

Comment: `Reload` the page once you change the device..

Comment: That didn't do anything it just changes back to the iPhone case image.

Comment: There is no select element in Fiddle..

Comment: try going to the actual site and see, it's a lot of code to sort through and post on the fiddle, http://www.matthewmwalker.com/sweetbriar/index.html

Comment: actually the image was just hard cached so i cleared my cache and it worked.....smallest things sometimes lol. Thanks!